# Magento 2 pass data from Controller to Block and display in Template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, controllers

I'm a little bit stuck. I want to send a form and display it in a phtml.

Here is my code:

**1. Controller `Search.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SearchStores\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

//use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward\Factory;

class ReadSearch extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory; 

    protected $_coreRegistry;


    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory, Registry $coreRegistry, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory; 

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {


       $search_word = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search');
      // $search_word = $this->getRequest()->getPost('search');


         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();


        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Vendor\SearchStores\Block\ShowResult')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_SearchStores::results_modal.phtml')
            ->setData('search',$search_word)
            ->toHtml();
       $result->setData(['output' => $block]);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**2. Block `ShowResult.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\SearchStores\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ShowResult extends Template
{

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(Context $context, Registry $coreRegistry)
    {
       $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getSearchWord()
    {
         //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THE DATA FROM THE CONTROLLER
         return $this->getSearch();

    }
}
```

**3. xml `result_index_readsearch.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\SearchStores\Block\ShowResult" name="show_result" template="Vendor_SearchStores::results_modal.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**4. Template `results_modal.phtml`**

```
<?php
    echo $block->getSearchWord();
?>
```

> NOTE: I can get info in the controller but I don't know how to send it to Block. I try to display in template, but it seems that when I send the form, and display template, the form arrives before loading the template, so I see no data in template. Please suggest a solution.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace this code

1. Controller `Search.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SearchStores\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

//use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward\Factory;

class ReadSearch extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $searchWord = $this->getRequest()->getParam('search');
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('search_word')) {
            $this->_coreRegistry->unregister('search_word');
        }
        // set value to _coreRegistry variable  search_word
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('search_word', $searchWord);
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Vendor\SearchStores\Block\ShowResult')
            ->setTemplate('Vendor_SearchStores::results_modal.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
        $result->setData(['output' => $block]);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

2. Block `ShowResult.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SearchStores\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class ShowResult extends Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getSearchWord()
    {
        $searchWord = '';
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('search_word')) {
            $searchWord = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('search_word');
        }
        //HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO GET THE DATA FROM THE CONTROLLER
        return $searchWord;
    }
}
```

After making the above changes in your **Controller** and **Block** file, you can get a search word in your template file.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm, but is it a good practice to use Registry? greetings!

Comment: @OscarVazquez it will be deprecated in future Magento 2.4.x installations