# Magento 2.4.x: How to pass custom variable from controller to phtml file?

Tags: magento2, phtml, data, custom-variable

Is there a way to pass a variable from controller to a phtml file without using registry?
I tried this: [Magento 2 pass data from Controller to Block and display in Template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294975/magento-2-pass-data-from-controller-to-block-and-display-in-template)
but it is not working.

Comment: You can use with static variable.

Comment: private static $coll;
set from controller and get from block.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to use a registry ? Is there a reason beyond this ?

You need to pass variables threw controller and block depending on how the templates is defined.

For example :

Template definition

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
   name="magemastery.first.layout.example"
   template="MageMastery_FirstLayout::example.phtml" />
```

Passing the variable

```
public function execute() {
/** @var Page $page */
$page = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);

/** @var Template $block */
$block = $page->getLayout()->getBlock('magemastery.first.layout.example');
$block->setData('custom_parameter', 'Data from the Controller');

return $page;
}
```

Then in template : `$block->getData('custom_parameter');`

To get more details : https://magemastery.net/courses/magento-2-beginner/passing-data-from-controller-to-template

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me using magento 2.4.4-p2

Answer (score 1):

When you create your block with `$block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock');`, you can pass data to it using the 3rd argument to the createBlock function. For example:

```
    $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('module\Block\Adminhtml\CustomBlock', 'block name', ['data' => ['MyData' => 'value']]);
```

The data will then be accessible to your block through the $data array that is passed to it's constructor.

Comment: for further guidance read this article for your understanding.
        https://magemastery.net/courses/magento-2-beginner/passing-data-from-controller-to-template

Answer (score 0):

it's also possible by ajax call.
By using that controller variable could be call in phtml file.

> Phtml file

```
 <div id ="Div_id"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'],function($) {
    jQuery(function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            var customurl = '<?= $block->getBaseUrl()."ultimatefaq/index/data";?>';
            $.ajax({
                        url: customurl
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json'
                    }).done(function( ControllerVariable )
                    { jQuery("Div_id").append(ControllerVariable
                         });
          });
      });
   });
```

> Controller file

```
<?php

   namespace vendor\module\Controller\Data;

    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
     use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Data extends Action
   {
   protected $_coreRegistry = null;
   protected $request;
   protected $resultPageFactory;
   protected $layoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
   ) {
       $this->resultPageFactory  = $resultPageFactory;
       $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
       parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * To create controller function
 * @return variable
 */

public function execute()
{
    $data = "Controller Data that woulde be dispalyed on phtml";
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $result = $resultJson->setData($data);
    return $result;
}
```

}

I hope it will work perfectely!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with static variable like below.

Controller class.

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
class Index extends Action
{    
    protected $pageFactory;    
    protected $blockdata; 
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,        
        \Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Index\Index $blockdata
    )
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;        
        $this->blockdata = $blockdata;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {   $page = $this->pageFactory->create();
        //$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        //$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        //$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
        $collection = 'yourvariable';
        $this->blockdata->setColl($collection);
        return $page;             
        
    }
}
```

Your Block class would be like.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private static $coll;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {          
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function setColl($c)
    {        
        self::$coll = $c;     
    }
    public function getCustomdata()
    {
        $coll = self::$coll;        
        return $coll;
    }
}
```

And In use in phtml file from Block.

```
<?php
echo $block->getCustomdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to work on same requirement and i achieved as below.

Controller Class

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    private PageFactory $pageFactory;
    private RequestInterface $request;

    public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      PageFactory $pageFactory,
      RequestInterface $request
    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
       $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       $this->request->setParams(['data1' => 'value1', 'data2' => 'value2']);
       return $this->pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Frontend Layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Index" name="index" template="Vendor_Module::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Block Class

Vendor\Module\Block\Index.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;


use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Index extends Template
{
  private RequestInterface $request;

  public function __construct(
      Context $context,
      RequestInterface $request,
      array $data = []
  ) {
      parent::__construct($context, $data);
      $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function getControllerData()
  {
      return $this->request;
  }
}
```

In Index.phtml file

You can get Data as below

```
<?php

     /* @var Vendor\Module\Block\Index $block */

    $controllerData = $block->getControllerData();
    print_r($controllerData->getParams());
```

Hope it helps!!